# How can I output rational numbers in properly formatted parentheses?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to output this:

[image]

If I input it like that, the output removes the parentheses, leaving just:

[image]

What I tried:

```
"("<>ToString[TraditionalForm[15/2]]<>")"
```

But then the parentheses come out too small:

[image]

How can I retain proper size parentheses in the output?

Comment: Before you get many different solutions, you should perhaps specify more clearly what is your actual use case of this. Do you want to be able to copy&paste the output? Do you actually want to use this for more complicated expressions, or do you really want just one fraction in the output?

Comment: [List of unicode brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535172/list-of-all-unicodes-open-close-brackets).

Comment: @Domen I need to convert it to a string and place in the overscript at a vertex in a graph. I accepted yours, it just repeats exactly the way it is in the input.

Comment: @Syed Well thanks, but I cannot say I figure out how to use it straight away

Comment: It is for reference in case someone decides to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with boxes.

```
DisplayForm[RowBox[{"(", ToBoxes[15/2], ")"}]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this is just for display purpose, why not simply use MaTeX?

```
e = 15/2;
g = MaTeX["\\left(" <> ToString[TeXForm[e]] <> "\\right)", Magnification -> 2];
g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure this can be also done uses "boxes" and such also. But I am not good with Boxes formatting.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be:

```
ToString@TraditionalForm@MatrixForm[{15/2}]
```

that gives:

[image]